# Calling asp.net webApi through restclient throws exception "Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 69, position 41."

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rest-client

I am calling Asp.net WebApi from C# code via RestSharp using below code

```
 RestClient Client = new RestClient();

                Client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:27156");
                var request = new RestRequest("api/GetUserName", Method.POST);
                UserDto user = new UserDto { Ldap = "rahkuma"};
                request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

                //request.AddJsonBody(user);
                request.AddBody(user);
                var response = Client.Execute<UserDto>(request);
```

> The service throwing StatusCode : NotFound and ErrorException "Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 69, position 41."
>   I am able to consume it from AngularJs but from C#(WebForm) using restclient it is throwing exception. 
>   Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
>   The Web API  Controller Code is below

```
[HttpPost]
    public ResponseModel<UserDto> GetUserName(UserDto user)
    {
        string Role = "Read";


        ResponseModel<UserDto> response = null;
        try
        {
            var res = _accountLogic.GetUserName(new UserDto { Ldap = Utilities.Decrypt(user.Ldap) });

            if (res != null)
            {
                res.Ldap = user.Ldap;
                var roleDetail = _accountLogic.GetUserRoles(res.EmpLdap);
                if (roleDetail != null)
                {
                    res.Role = roleDetail.Role;
                    res.LockEdit = roleDetail.LockEdit;
                    res.ManagementAdjPlug = roleDetail.ManagementAdjPlug;
                }

                response = new ResponseModel<UserDto>();
                response.Data = res;
                response.ResponseStatus = Common.Enums.ResponseStatus.Sucess;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            response = new ResponseModel<UserDto>();
            response.ResponseStatus = Common.Enums.ResponseStatus.Error;
            response.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            throw ex;
        }


        return response;
    }
```

**I am also attaching the exception detail Image below**[image: web Api exception detail image]

Comment: Can you show the code of the controller you are hitting?

Comment: Hi Daniel i have added the controller code.This is working fine when consuming it with angularjs but with c# it is not working

Comment: 1. Which is line 69 in the code you showed? 2. Can you show the AngularJS code that is working correctly?

Comment: Hi Maria below angular code is working fine 
 var _getUserInfo = function (sldap) {
           var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: serviceBase + 'Account/GetUserName',
            data: JSON.stringify({ Ldap: sldap }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function (response) {
            _Appuser = response.Data;

            deferred.resolve(response);
        }).error(function (err, status) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

Comment: @rahulrathore I think the more pertinent question is Maria's first: "Which is line 69 in the code you showed?"

Comment: Based on your image, it seems the problem is with your HTML request and response (your error is usually associated with XML trying to parse spaces). Could we see your request string and that code (its not fully visible in the image.)

Comment: @Keyur: i dont know why xml issue is there i am passing json data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was missing Api controller Name from the request Url

When i make change it from `var request = new RestRequest("api/GetUserName", Method.POST);`

To This`var request = new RestRequest("api/Account/GetUserName", Method.POST);`

it works fine. The Complete code is below

```
 Client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:27156");
            var request = new RestRequest("api/Account/GetUserName", Method.POST);
            UserDto user = new UserDto { Ldap = "rahkuma"};
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            //request.AddJsonBody(user);
            request.AddBody(user);
            var response = Client.Execute<UserDto>(request);
```

It  was a silly mistake from my side and thanks to all of you who supported and helped me

Answer (score 0):

Could you try these modifications to your request and see if it helps:

```
RestClient Client = new RestClient("http://localhost:27156");
var request = new RestRequest("api/GetUserName", Method.POST);
UserDto user = new UserDto { Ldap = "rahkuma"};
request.Method = Method.POST;
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.Method = Method.POST;

//request.AddJsonBody(user);
//request.AddBody(user);
request.AddParameter("application/json", user, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response = Client.Execute<UserDto>(request);
```

Edited:

```
//request.AddJsonBody(user);
request.AddBody(user);    //same as your original
//request.AddParameter("application/json", user, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response = Client.Execute(request); //modified
```

And put a breakpoint after that, or display the response, to see what exactly is returned.

Comment: Tried your request but still the same exception.

Comment: Hmm, could you try with the modifications?

Comment: The mistake was from my side and it was missing controller name from the URL